# Overriding static method produces an error

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

In the `B` class I concealed (override) static method `foo()` from `A` class.
So why

```
A object = new B();
object.foo();
```

outputs 'A', but not 'B'?

```
public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A object = new B();
        object.foo();
    }
}

class A
{
    public static void foo()
    {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public static void foo()
    {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

Comment: @mr1554 he knows, which is why he added the (conceal) in his question

Comment: @Denis_newbie you declared it to be of type A, what exactly did you expect?

Comment: @Stultuske ordinary (not static) methods are invoked from real object class, not from reference

Comment: Overriding means looking for an implementation from the run-time type of the object. Static methods are looked up on the declared class (which in this case is `A`) not on the object (which happens to be of type `B`).

Comment: @Denis_newbie your point being?